# Algebra problem stumping me

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, puzzle

I have recently run into an algebra problem that goes as follows.

Using the digits $1$ to $9$,
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
    A + B + C + D &= EF \\
    E + F + G + H &= CJ \\
    B + G + J     &= ?D \\
    \text{total} &= B?
\end{align}
\right.
$$

also $A-H > F$
where each letter is a different unique number.

I believe when it says $EF$ it does not mean $E \cdot F$, but more like if answer was $15$, $E = 1$ and $F = 5$ sort of thing.

Been working on this for hours, even attempted to write a computer program to help solve but to no avail.

Any tips on how to solve (or a work through of it) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `total` refer to `A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+J`?

Comment: The sum of the digits $1 + \cdots + 9 = 45$, so I'm not sure what the total equation means if $1 \le B \le 9$.

Comment: Was meant to be B?, not B. For some reason it didn't save, meaning 4+ a number(assuming B is 4)

Comment: Rewrite $EF$ as $10E+F$, $?D$ as $10X+D$ and $B?$ as $10B+X$. Assuming that the question marks represent the same number, else use $X$ and $Y$ instead.

Comment: @user112061 If you use $X$ in the first $?$, I'd use $Y$ as the second $?$.  Maybe $X=Y$.  Maybe not.  But setting both $?$ to $X$ only considers the first possibility.

Comment: @TravisBemrose Of course, but I just assumed that it was known by the original poster whether or not they were necessarily the same. Of course if they might be different use $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: ? Can be any number from 1-9. would be X and Y I believe, could be different or the same as any of the others.

Comment: Hmm, I programmed everything I can see about the problem into Mathematica, and it reduced it to 31 different possible cases.  (That was assuming $total=1+2+\dots+9=45$ which implies $B=4$ and the second $?=5$.)

Comment: @user144808 Is there anything in the problem that's missing above?  Where did $A-H>F$ come from?  It seems odd for that not to be included in the list of equations.

Comment: In only 1 of those 31 cases, is the first $?$ a $2$.  In the other 30 cases, it's a $1$.

Comment: In all 31 cases, $C=1$. $E$ is either a $1$ or $2$ (with approximately equal likelihood).

Comment: @Travis Bemrose: If $1\le A,B,C,D\le 9$, then $1\le E\le 3$; if $C=1$, do you agree that $E=2$?

Comment: @MattAllegro No, $E\in \{1,2\}$.  I'll paste what I've got as an answer.

Comment: I believe you should assume total is the table total, $EF + CJ + xD = By$.

Comment: OP also crossposted to [Mathematica.StackExchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46546/algebra-problem/46547#46547)

Comment: Ya I had posted it on the wrong StackExchange originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
    A + B + C + D &= EF \\
    E + F + G + H &= CJ \\
    B + G + J     &= xD \\
    EF + CJ + xD  &= By \\
            A - H &\gt F
\end{align}
\right.
$$

$\begin{align} \\
A &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
B &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
C &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
D &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
E &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
F &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
G &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
H &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
J &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
x &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\  
y &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
\end{align}$

$$A + B + C + D \le 6+ 7 + 8 + 9 = 30 \\
F \ne 0 \\
\begin{align} &\implies EF \le 29, CJ \le 29 \\
              &\implies E,C \in \{1,2\} \end{align}$$

$$B + G + J \le 7 + 8 + 9 = 24 \\
xD \le 24 \implies x \in \{1,2\}$$

$$F + J + D \le 7 + 8 + 9 = 24 \implies \text{carry} \le 2 \\
4 = 1 + 2 + 1 + 0 \le E + C + x + \text{carry} \le 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 7 \\
\implies B \in \{4,5,6,7\}$$

$\begin{align} \\
C &\in \{1,2\} \\
E &\in \{1,2\} \\
B &\in \{4,5,6,7\} \\
A &\in \{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
D &\in \{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
F &\in \{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
G &\in \{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
H &\in \{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
J &\in \{3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
x &\in \{1,2\} \\  
y &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
\end{align}$

$$A > F + H \ge 3 + 4 = 7 \implies A \in \{8,9\} \\
9 = 3 + 6 > F + H \ge 3 + 4 \implies F,H \in \{3,4,5\} \\
F + H \in \left\{ \begin{align} 3+4=7 \\
3+5=8 \end{align} \right. \\
3 \in \{F,H\}$$

$\begin{align} \\
C &\in \{1,2\} \\
E &\in \{1,2\} \\
F &\in \{3,4,5\} \\
H &\in \{3,4,5\} \\
B &\in \{4,5,6,7\} \\
D &\in \{4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
G &\in \{4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
J &\in \{4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
A &\in \{8,9\} \\
x &\in \{1,2\} \\  
y &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
\end{align}$

$$EF \in \{ 13, 14, 15, 23, 24, 25 \} \\
EF = A + B + C + D \ge 8 + 4 + 1 + 4 = 17 \\
\implies E=2 \implies C=1$$

$\begin{align} \\
C &\in \{1\} \\
E &\in \{2\} \\
F &\in \{3,4,5\} \\
H &\in \{3,4,5\} \\
B &\in \{4,5,6,7\} \\
D &\in \{4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
G &\in \{4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
J &\in \{4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
A &\in \{8,9\} \\
x &\in \{1,2\} \\  
y &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
\end{align}$

$$E + F + G + H = CJ \implies F + H + G = 8 + J \\
F + H \in \{7,8\} \\
F + H = 8 \implies G = J \text{ (contradiction)} \\
\implies F + H = 7 = 3 + 4 \implies 5 \notin \{F,H\} \\
\implies \{F,H\} = \{3,4\}$$

$$\implies G = 1 + J \qquad (*)$$

$\begin{align} \\
C &\in \{1\} \\
E &\in \{2\} \\
F &\in \{3,4\} \\
H &\in \{3,4\} \\
B &\in \{5,6,7\} \\
J &\in \{5,6,7,8\} \\
G &\in \{6,7,8,9\} \\
D &\in \{5,6,7,8,9\} \\
A &\in \{8,9\} \\
x &\in \{1,2\} \\  
y &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
\end{align}$

$$\begin{align}
J + G + B &= xD \\
5 + 6 + 7 &= 18 \\
6 + 7 + 5 &= 18 \\
7 + 8 + 5 &= 20 \, \, (D \ne 0) \\
7 + 8 + 6 &= 21 \, \, (D \ne 1) \\
8 + 9 + 5 &= 22 \, \, (D \ne 2) \\
8 + 9 + 6 &= 23 \, \, (D \ne 3) \\
8 + 9 + 7 &= 24 \, \, (D \ne 4)
\end{align}$$

$$\implies D=8 \implies A=9$$

$\begin{align} \\
C &\in \{1\} \\
E &\in \{2\} \\
F &\in \{3,4\} \\
H &\in \{3,4\} \\
B &\in \{5,7\} \\
J &\in \{5,6\} \\
G &\in \{6,7\} \\
D &\in \{8\} \\
A &\in \{9\} \\
x &\in \{1\} \\  
y &\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} \\
\end{align}$

$$A + B + C + D = EF \implies B + 18 = F + 20 \implies B = F + 2 \\
\implies F = 3, \, B = 5 \\
\implies H = 4, \, J = 6, \, G = 7 \\
\implies y = 7$$

$\begin{align} \\
C &\in \{1\} \\
E &\in \{2\} \\
F &\in \{3\} \\
H &\in \{4\} \\
B &\in \{5\} \\
J &\in \{6\} \\
G &\in \{7\} \\
D &\in \{8\} \\
A &\in \{9\} \\
x &\in \{1\} \\  
y &\in \{7\} \\
\end{align}$

Comment: First one to show work:D Great job, I can see how you would go about the problem now.

Comment: @user144808 Just for fun I tried doing it with only symbols, no words, and remain clear. ;-) I couldn't find an obvious and universal contradiction symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- "$EF$" means $10\cdot E+F$
- $total$ means $EF+CJ+xD+By$

Using Mathematica:
Input:

```
Reduce[a+b+c+d==e*10+f
    && e+f+g+h==c*10+j
    && b+g+j ==x*10+d
    && 10*(e+c+x)+(f+j+d)==b*10+y
    && a-h>f
    && (a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|j|x|y) \[Element] Integers
    && 1<=a<=9
    && 1<=b<=9
    && 1<=c<=9
    && 1<=d<=9
    && 1<=e<=9
    && 1<=f<=9
    && 1<=g<=9
    && 1<=h<=9
    && 1<=j<=9
    && 1<=x<=9
    && 1<=y<=9]
```

The output was 45 different possibilities.  Filtering for uniqueness left 1 solution:

```
(a==9 && b==5 && c==1 && d==8 && e==2 && f==3 && g==7 && h==4 && j==6 && x==1 && y==7)
```

Now that we know the right assumptions that lead to a unique solution ... who can show him how to solve it by hand?

Comment: Ya:D that would be impressive to see.

Comment: I find it funny that my first (wrong) coded answer (incorrect assumption) received an upvote, but this correct coded answer hasn't yet. (Of course the manual solution is the best because it leads to understanding.)

Comment: nice approach using x,y for the "?" instead of messing with `Mod` Worth a note mathematica crunches all the permutations to find the solution by brute force in 5 seconds..

Answer (score 1):

There's something missing to the problem, or we've made an invalid assumption.

Assumptions:

- "$EF$" means $10\cdot E+F$
- $total$ means $A+B+\dots +J$ and it equals $45$

  - Which means $B=4$

Using Mathematica:
Input:

```
Reduce[a+b+c+d==e*10+f
    && e+f+g+h==c*10+j
    && b+g+j ==x*10+d
    && b==4
    && a-h>f
    && (a|c|d|e|f|g|h|j|x) \[Element] Integers
    && 1<=a<=9
    && 1<=c<=9
    && 1<=d<=9
    && 1<=e<=9
    && 1<=f<=9
    && 1<=g<=9
    && 1<=h<=9
    && 1<=j<=9
    && 1<=x<=9]
```

Output:

```
((a==3 && c==1 && d==3 && e==1 && f==1 && g==8 && h==1 && j==1 && x==1)||
 (a==4 && c==1 && d==2 && e==1 && f==1 && g==7 && h==2 && j==1 && x==1)||
 (a==5 && c==1 && d==1 && e==1 && f==1 && g==6 && h==3 && j==1 && x==1)||
 (a==5 && c==1 && d==2 && e==1 && f==2 && g==7 && h==1 && j==1 && x==1)||
 (a==5 && c==1 && d==3 && e==1 && f==3 && g==7 && h==1 && j==2 && x==1)||
 (a==6 && c==1 && d==1 && e==1 && f==2 && g==6 && h==2 && j==1 && x==1)||
 (a==6 && c==1 && d==2 && e==1 && f==3 && g==6 && h==2 && j==2 && x==1)||
 (a==7 && c==1 && d==1 && e==1 && f==3 && g==5 && h==3 && j==2 && x==1)||
 (a==7 && c==1 && d==1 && e==1 && f==3 && g==6 && h==1 && j==1 && x==1)||
 (a==7 && c==1 && d==2 && e==1 && f==4 && g==6 && h==1 && j==2 && x==1)||
 (a==7 && c==1 && d==3 && e==1 && f==5 && g==6 && h==1 && j==3 && x==1)||
 (a==7 && c==1 && d==9 && e==2 && f==1 && g==9 && h==4 && j==6 && x==1)||
 (a==8 && c==1 && d==1 && e==1 && f==4 && g==5 && h==2 && j==2 && x==1)||
 (a==8 && c==1 && d==2 && e==1 && f==5 && g==5 && h==2 && j==3 && x==1)||
 (a==8 && c==1 && d==8 && e==2 && f==1 && g==8 && h==5 && j==6 && x==1)||
 (a==8 && c==1 && d==8 && e==2 && f==1 && g==9 && h==3 && j==5 && x==1)||
 (a==8 && c==1 && d==9 && e==2 && f==2 && g==8 && h==5 && j==7 && x==1)||
 (a==8 && c==1 && d==9 && e==2 && f==2 && g==9 && h==3 && j==6 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==1 && e==1 && f==5 && g==4 && h==3 && j==3 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==1 && e==1 && f==5 && g==5 && h==1 && j==2 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==1 && e==1 && f==5 && g==9 && h==3 && j==8 && x==2)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==2 && e==1 && f==6 && g==5 && h==1 && j==3 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==3 && e==1 && f==7 && g==5 && h==1 && j==4 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==7 && e==2 && f==1 && g==7 && h==6 && j==6 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==7 && e==2 && f==1 && g==8 && h==4 && j==5 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==7 && e==2 && f==1 && g==9 && h==2 && j==4 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==8 && e==2 && f==2 && g==7 && h==6 && j==7 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==8 && e==2 && f==2 && g==8 && h==4 && j==6 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==8 && e==2 && f==2 && g==9 && h==2 && j==5 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==9 && e==2 && f==3 && g==8 && h==4 && j==7 && x==1)||
 (a==9 && c==1 && d==9 && e==2 && f==3 && g==9 && h==2 && j==6 && x==1))
&& b==-a-c-d+10 e+f
```

Comment: Yeah, we are talking of a system of 3-4 equations in 8-9 unknowns...

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that definition of total is how I'd read it, but rather as the sum of the RHS of the above equations. I'd also note that the constraints include the variables being unique and with digit values. That's a lot more constraining than just counting the 3-4 basic linear equations implies.

Comment: If the variables had to be unique would that change it? Because it might be that A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J are all unique (like if one is 5, no others can be 5).

Comment: Ah, yes!  A missing assumption.

Comment: @Keith The sum of the RHS view gives 45 possibilities (before enforcing uniqueness).  Give me a bit to encode the uniqueness.

Comment: @user144808 Hmm, with the 36 inequalities enforcing uniqueness it's taking too long to run, to expect a good solution. (For either interpretation of $total$.)

Comment: I assume mathematica would let you could just filter the output for uniqueness.  No reason that uniqueness should take noticably longer to run.

Comment: @DanielV The output is basically just a text string (display wise).  There may be functions that would do that, but I'm still new to Mathematica.  The fastest way for me to try that would be to dump it into Excel.  (But the long time makes me think none of those 31 satisfy the uniqueness condition.)

Comment: Yep, None of those 31 satisfy uniqueness. (For $total=45$.  Let me check $total=RHS$.)

Comment: @user144808 I meant missing from my formula, not your question. ;-)

Comment: You are interpreting total differently than how this problem probably intended, try EF + CJ + xD = By.

Comment: @DanielV See 2 comments up, 2 minutes before your comment.  "Let me check $total=RHS$." :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned using a program, and the generalization of this problem is NP-complete anyway, here is the solution:

```
A:9 B:5 C:1 D:8 E:2 F:3 G:7 H:4 I:6 x:1 y:7
```

The "main part" of the code:

```
int main() {

  int digits = 9;
  int digit_array[digits];

  for (permutation_initialize(digit_array, digits, 1);
       permutation_finished  (digit_array, digits, 1);
       permutation_next      (digit_array, digits, 1)) {

    int a = digit_array[0];
    int b = digit_array[1];
    int c = digit_array[2];
    int d = digit_array[3];
    int e = digit_array[4];
    int f = digit_array[5];
    int g = digit_array[6];
    int h = digit_array[7];
    int j = digit_array[8];

    int sum1 = a + b + c + d;
    int sum2 = e + f + g + h;
    int sum3 = b + g + j;

    if (sum1 != 10*e + f) continue;
    if (sum2 != 10*c + j) continue;
    if (a - h <= f) continue;

    for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x++) {

      if (sum3 != 10*x + d) continue;
      if (((sum1 + sum2 + sum3) / 10) != b) continue;
      print_array(digit_array, digits);
      printf("x:%d y:%d\n", x, (sum1 + sum2 + sum3)%10);
   }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I realize this is only comment worthy but it's too long, and hopefully it will help motivate due to the demonstration that there is a unique answer.

Comment: $y$ is $7$, not $5$.  But you did beat me to the other letters by a bit.

Comment: Ah thanks, had a division where I should have had a modulus and so ended up printing 'b' instead of 'y'.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to approach this. In the following I assume:
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,J are distinct from 1 to 9 and total refers to the sum of the previous equations.

The following Mathematica code firstly reduces the candidate partitions of `Range[9]` to achieve first two criteria then searches this reduced space for solutions.This is a little faster than looking through 362880 permutations.

```
ran = Range[9];
sub = Subsets[ran, {4}];
cand = Select[
   Select[Select[
     Select[Flatten[
       Map[Function[
         x, {#, x, Total@#, Total@x, Intersection[#, x]} & /@ sub], 
        sub], 1], Last@# == {} &], 
     Not[Or[IntegerDigits[#[[3]]][[2]] == 0, 
        IntegerDigits[#[[4]]][[2]] == 0]] &], 
    Length@Intersection[#[[2]], IntegerDigits[#[[3]]]] == 2 &],
   And[
     MemberQ[#[[1]], IntegerDigits[#[[4]]][[1]]], 
     Not[MemberQ[#[[1]], IntegerDigits[#[[4]]][[2]]]], 
     Not[MemberQ[#[[2]], IntegerDigits[#[[4]]][[2]]]]] &
   ];
fun[u_, v_, w_] := 
 Module[{pu, pv, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, r1, r2, r3, tp},
  pu = Permutations[u];
  pv = Permutations[v];
  r1 = Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> #] & /@ pu;
  r2 = Thread[{e, f, g, h} -> #] & /@ pv;
  r3 = {j -> IntegerDigits[w][[2]]};
  tp = Partition[Flatten[Tuples[{r1, r2, r3}]], 9];
  #[[All, 2]] & /@ 
   Union[Select[tp, 
     And[a + b + c + d == 10 e + f, e + f + g + h == 10 c + j, 
        b + g + j > 10, Mod[b + g + j, 10] == d, 
        IntegerPart[(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + b + g + j)/10] == 
         b] /. # &]]
  ]
arg = cand[[All, {1, 2, 4}]];
answers = Cases[fun @@ # & /@ arg, Except[{}]];
dat[x_] := 
 Join[x, {Total[x[[1 ;; 4]]], Total[x[[5 ;; 8]]], 
   x[[2]] + x[[7]] + x[[9]], 
   Total[{Total[x[[1 ;; 4]]], Total[x[[5 ;; 8]]], 
     x[[2]] + x[[7]] + x[[9]]}]}]
tab = Column[
  TableForm[#, 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
        "j", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"}}] & /@ Map[dat, answers, {2}]]
```

I apologize for the ugliness of the code.
It yields the following (where c1,c2,c3,c4 are the constraints of the puzzle, e.g. c1= A+B+C+D=EF}
[image]

**Update**

In light of the additional constraint mentioned in comment:

1. `cand` selects two disjoint subsets of {1,2,3,...,9}of size 4 with the properties that the first subset sums to a two digit number whose digits are in the second subset and the sum of the digits in this second subset has first digit in first subset.
2. `fun` then evaluates candidate partitions and selects the order that satisfies the constraints. This is applied to relevant elements of `cand`
3. `dat` is just a way to display solution and `tab` displays it.

In light of constraint A-H>F here is the trivially modified code:

```
ran = Range[9];
sub = Subsets[ran, {4}];
cand = Select[
   Select[Select[
     Select[Flatten[
       Map[Function[
         x, {#, x, Total@#, Total@x, Intersection[#, x]} & /@ sub], 
        sub], 1], Last@# == {} &], 
     Not[Or[IntegerDigits[#[[3]]][[2]] == 0, 
        IntegerDigits[#[[4]]][[2]] == 0]] &], 
    Length@Intersection[#[[2]], IntegerDigits[#[[3]]]] == 2 &],
   And[
     MemberQ[#[[1]], IntegerDigits[#[[4]]][[1]]], 
     Not[MemberQ[#[[1]], IntegerDigits[#[[4]]][[2]]]], 
     Not[MemberQ[#[[2]], IntegerDigits[#[[4]]][[2]]]]] &
   ];
fun[u_, v_, w_] := 
 Module[{pu, pv, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, r1, r2, r3, tp},
  pu = Permutations[u];
  pv = Permutations[v];
  r1 = Thread[{a, b, c, d} -> #] & /@ pu;
  r2 = Thread[{e, f, g, h} -> #] & /@ pv;
  r3 = {j -> IntegerDigits[w][[2]]};
  tp = Partition[Flatten[Tuples[{r1, r2, r3}]], 9];
  #[[All, 2]] & /@ 
   Union[Select[tp, 
     And[a + b + c + d == 10 e + f, e + f + g + h == 10 c + j, 
        b + g + j > 10, Mod[b + g + j, 10] == d, 
        IntegerPart[(a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + b + g + j)/10] == 
         b, a - h > f] /. # &]]
  ]
arg = cand[[All, {1, 2, 4}]];
answers = Cases[fun @@ # & /@ arg, Except[{}]];
dat[x_] := 
 Join[x, {Total[x[[1 ;; 4]]], Total[x[[5 ;; 8]]], 
   x[[2]] + x[[7]] + x[[9]], 
   Total[{Total[x[[1 ;; 4]]], Total[x[[5 ;; 8]]], 
     x[[2]] + x[[7]] + x[[9]]}]}]
tab = Column[
  TableForm[#, 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", 
        "j", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4"}}] & /@ Map[dat, answers, {2}]]
```

yielding the unique solution:

[image]

Comment: I'm new enough to Mathematica that I don't follow your code.  Since you have 2 solutions, I'm guessing you didn't use $A-H>F$?  Your second solution matches the others here; your first satisfies the sum equations, but not that inequality.

Comment: @TravisBemrose I answered Mathematica post which did not have this constraint, hence not unique. Once add this constraint, a trivial matter, unique solution emerges.

Comment: @TravisBemrose see update

Answer (score 0):

Solutions of this problem can be easily obtained in Mathematica.

It turns out that there is just one solution, as it should be for this type of puzzle.

The equations are

```
eq1 = a + b + c + d == 10 e + f;
eq2 = e + f + g + h == 10 c + j;
eq3 = b + g + j == 10 x + d;
eq4 = 10 e + f + 10 c + j + 10 x + d == 10 b + y;
eq5 = a - h == f + z;
```

Here we have modified the inequality to an equation eq5.
Notice that the auxiliary quantities x, y, and z are also decimal digits, but they are allowed to be equal to one of the main variables.

The condition of all variables being a decimal place is

```
dec = And @@ Thread[1 <= {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, x, y, z} <= 9];
```

The solution is obtained in a matter of seconds:

```
sol = Solve[Reduce[eq1 && eq2 && eq3 && eq4 && eq5 && dec, Integers]];
Length[sol]

(* Out[192]= 45 *)
```

Now we impose on these 45 tuples the condition that all main variables {a, ...,j} are pairwise different.

```
sel = Select[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, x, y, z} /. sol, 
  Length[Union[Take[#, {1, 9}]]] == 9 &]

(* Out[187]= {{9, 5, 1, 8, 2, 3, 7, 4, 6, 1, 7, 2}} *)
```

This is the unique solution.

Writen in replacement format it becomes:

```
List @@ Inner[Rule, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, x, y, z}, sel[[1]]]

(*
Out[188]= {a -> 9, b -> 5, c -> 1, d -> 8, e -> 2, f -> 3, g -> 7, h -> 4, j -> 6,  x -> 1, y -> 7, z -> 2}
*)
```

*Observation*

There are two obvious points in the code which can certainly be improved

1) the selection should be done immediately in the conditions to be fed into Reduce[]

2) The replacement form should have a more elegant form

Comment: @ubpdqn I found this nice problem on your page. You might be interested in having a look at my solution.